# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: function not found while exporting a typescript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, export, es6-promise

I have created a ts file in a node api and exporting that.

Below is the code of **myClass.ts** file

```
class myClass{

    firstFunction(firstParam, secondParam) {
        return firstParam + secondParam
    };
}

module.exports.myClass = myClass;
```

there is one js file which is index.js

Below is the code

```
const myClass= require('./myClass.ts');

myFunction(){
    myClass.firstFunction("firstValue", "secondValue");

}
```

**But with the above code im getting the below exception.**

```
**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: myClass.firstFunction is not a function**
    at "myMachinePath\index.js:368:20"
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
warning.js:27
(node:14944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async 
function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Is it possible to use a ts file in a js using require?

I have tried to install

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
```

But i still get the same exception. I cant change my js file to ts.

**Update**

If i make the below changes to myClass.ts file it is working fine. Not sure if that is a correct approach.

```
myClass = {

    firstFunction(firstParam, secondParam) {
        return firstParam + secondParam
    };
}

module.exports = myClass;
```

Comment: code in your ts file does not seem to be typescript.

Comment: @AZ_ it is typescript actually, why you feel so it is not?

Answer (score 0):

Either you make you make your method static

```
class myClass{

    static firstFunction(firstParam, secondParam) {
        return firstParam + secondParam
    };
}

module.exports = myClass;
```

Or create an instance of the class then invoke the function

```
   const MyClass= require('./myClass.ts');

    myFunction(){
        const myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.firstFunction("firstValue", "secondValue");

    }
```

Comment: i have tried that as well, below is the exception i get
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: myClass is not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call method without creating object of class(`myClass`) please check below solved code for you problem :

**myClass.ts**

```
class myClass{

    constructor(){}

    static firstFunction(firstParam, secondParam) {
        return firstParam + secondParam
    };
}
module.exports.myClass = myClass;
```

**index.js**

```
const myClass= require('./myClass.ts');

myFunction(){
    new myClass().firstFunction("firstValue", "secondValue");
}
```

Either you can export directly object from the **myClass.ts** file like below :

```
module.exports.myClass = new myClass();
```

So you don't need to create object in **index.js** file:

```
const myClass= require('./myClass.ts');
myFunction(){
    myClass.firstFunction("firstValue", "secondValue");
}
```

Hope this solution will work for you.

Comment: this also doesnt work, now im feeling its more of a configuration issue rather than code problem. Do i need to install any node module / library for promises etc?